# How to use session variable in PHP for mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, session-variables

I have no experience on using session variables for mysql queries. This is the sentence that I would like to use session variable:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE pagename='$_SESSION['pro_title']'");
```

Please let me know how to do it in correct way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) can make things a bit clearer. Using %s here because I assumed that 'pro_title' is a string.

```
$query = sprintf( "UPDATE viewcounter SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE  pagename='%s'", $_SESSION['pro_title']);
mysql_query($query);
```

Note: beware that the mysql extension has been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and will be removed in PHP 7.0. [More information](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

you mispell the quotes. Also you'd better use ID for pages instead of page titles.

mysql_query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE pagename='{$_SESSION['pro_title']}'");

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Quote, Try this piece of code:

mysql_query("UPDATE viewcounter SET views = views+1 WHERE pagename='" . $_SESSION['pro_title'] . "');